# Passing a Pointer as an Argument in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c

How would one go about using the pointer parameter if given a function like this:

```
int testFunction(int *){  
}
```

I understand that a pointer is being passed as the parameter, but how do I use that pointer given that there is no variable name after the pointer?

Comment: You can't without naming that argument. What's stopping you from naming that argument?

Comment: is this c++? in c this code will not compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should name the argument. See this link for a [tutorial](http://www.nongnu.org/c-prog-book/online/x641.html)

Comment: This is true, but c++ allows parameters without a name, I don't know what is that useful for, but the OP probably uses a c++ compiler, still your answer is correct

Comment: @iharob: _"c++ allows parameters without a name, I don't know what is that useful for"_ - for example in overload resolution with what is known as _tags_, parameters that are not used other than to choose another overload, and their creation will be completely optimized away, unless the optimizer is a toy one.

Comment: @iharob: It's useful when you have a prototype which you expect to be overridden, and in which some base classes don't need the parameters. Or in a template class where you expect the existence of a member function, but not all implementations need all the parameters. Not giving the parameter a name is a clear indication that it won't be used, so lint warnings can get that right.

Comment: @JohannGerell I see, after all i don't find function overloading a good thing, and in fact I think it's a bad thing that may cause more problems than solutions, because it forces you to remember stuff. The second argument makes more sense though, for Abstract Classes which is one of the very few things I like about c++.

Comment: @iharob, well _tags_ are heavily used in templated code and there they make more solutions possible than they cause problems. :)

Comment: Is there some reason why this would be useful for a function defined outside of a class?  Since the OP was originally asking about C I assume that he was just compiling C code with a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 3):

Name of function parameters can be omitted from function prototypes (declarations)

```
int testFunction(int *);
```

You can't omit name of parameters from function definition.

Comment: You did see that the posted code is the function definition, didn't you? I still think the OP is using a c++ compiler.

Comment: @iharob; Where is code? If OP is using C++ compiler then he must know the difference between two languages.

Comment: That's why I asked him in the comments, but notice his code is `int testFunction(int *){}` it's a definition.

Comment: @iharob; Yes. Its a definition.

Answer (score -2):

You can get parameters from function's stack.

Before your function called, your program pushes parameters to stack. So you can define some internal variable in your function, and pop this parameter from stack into this variable.

For more information you have to research how do [C functions](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~chang/cs313.s02/stack.shtml) work.

Comment: It's not that this is false, it's that this is not the answer.

Comment: @iharob: Thanks. I was just trying to figure out how to comment on this. :)